# Trigger a workflow when an item is added and apply Permissions using ItemEvent receiver simultaneously

Tags: event-receivers, item-added, splist-custom-newform

**Scenario**:As per my requirement I need to create a **projectrequest** form  with `NEW/Edit/Display`. when I click on the add new item ,the new custom input form which is created using the **SP DESIGNER 2013** - say **projectrequestnewform**, should be populated.

Hence, I have created a  custom new form using `SP Designer 2013` with custom `html controls`, and other `JSOM` code for inserting into the `splist`,validation using `jQuery`, other js files. Below steps been used to populate the **projectrequestnewform** form.

1. Copied the **projectrequestnewform** into  `siteasets library` of my `publishing site collection`
2. Similarly, copied **projectrequesteditform** && **projectrequestdispform** into  `siteasets library`
3. Clicked on the `new item` from the `splist` and `edit the page` and added a `content editor web part` to give a link to this **projectrequestnewform** location: `/siteassets/projectrequestnewform.html`
4. Also the `siteassets library` contains the **projectrequestnewform.js** file that has the `JSOM`  code for `CRUD operations` on this `splist`.

when the input form **projectrequestnewform.html** is loaded on the page, it will be filled with many controls like `peoplepicker` and `dropdowns` populated from a `SPGroup`, `Textboxes` for entry and having submit,save and cancel  functionalities.

when the form's  save button is clicked it will simply insert the item into the `splist` and when submit button is clicked it will finally trigger some `approval workflow` thats created by `SP Wokrflow 2013 Template`. This was configured by using `SP Designer 2013`+ `Workflow Manager`.

**Problem**: As part of my reuirement, I also need to apply `itemlevelpermissions` when this item is inserted/updated. As per my below code,when I applied the `itemlevelpermissions feature`, permissions got applied to **projectrequestnewform.html** thats residing in the `siteassets` library instead of the `new item` got created in the **projectrequest** `splist`.

Also when my event receiver is triggered, I am getting the access denied error such that, i wont be able to add an item into this list.

**Question**:

1. I am stuck with how an item added eventreceiver thats targetted to apply the new item in the splist got deviated/applied to the permissions of the  the **projectrequestnewform.html** ?
2. Does the workflow thats been configured on this `SPList`'s when an item is added , influencing the `itemadded()` eventhandler ?
3. can a `splistitem` would be able to handle both `itemadded() eventhandler/receivers` and a SP D worflow ?
4. or my approach of triggering both itemadded/itemupdated() eventreceiver() for applying permissions on the `item` and trigger an workflow/approval process with multiple tasks **simultaneously** is **NOT ALLOWED** as per SharePoint Design ?

Has anyone faced this issue before?

**Code**:

```
 public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        //base.ItemUpdated(properties);


        SPUser currUser = properties.Web.CurrentUser;

        this.EventFiringEnabled = false;

        try
        {

            // if (properties.ListTitle.ToLower() == NPDListNames.ITEMLEVELPERMISSIONSLIST.ToString())
            // {

            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {

                SPSite CurrentSite = new SPSite(properties.SiteId);
                SPWeb CurrentWeb = CurrentSite.OpenWeb(properties.RelativeWebUrl);

                SPList CurrentList = CurrentWeb.Lists[properties.ListId];

                SPListItem CurrentListItem;
                CurrentListItem = 
         CurrentWeb.Lists[properties.ListId].
       GetItemById(properties.ListItem.ID);

  if (!CurrentListItem.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
                {
                    CurrentListItem.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
                    CurrentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                    SPRoleAssignmentCollection SPRoleAssColn = CurrentListItem.RoleAssignments;
                    for (int i = SPRoleAssColn.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        SPRoleAssignment roleAssignmentSingle = SPRoleAssColn[i];
                        System.Type t = roleAssignmentSingle.Member.GetType();
                        if (t.Name == "SPGroup" || t.Name == "SPUser")
                            SPRoleAssColn.Remove(i);
                    }
```

[image: custom-new-form-item]

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: hello, i have written my question, can you pls help, why my eventreceiver is applying permissions for the customnewform.html file thats residing in the siteassets lib instead of the custom list's  new item!!

Comment: @SaMolPP You can refine your question. Filter out unwanted details and throw more light on problem and question.

Comment: @AsadRefai , i have updated my question with details and code. I am facing this critical issue i my current project. It would be great, If you can help /suggest the approaches ,point me in the right direction,

Answer (score 2):

please insert a wait condition for 2-3 minutes at the beginning of the  designer workflow  and check once, so that  the  code in the event receiver will complete the execution and  workflow  action will start the after the wait condition. try this  and check once

Comment: the idea about adding a wait condition is seems ok, but somehow i am unable to get it work.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that both the item added event and the designer workflow will both get fired, not sure though which will get fired first but they are most likely both running at the same time. What might be a better approach, is to not run the sharepoint designer workflow until the item added event has triggered. In the item added event you can then trigger the workflow through CSOM code. Not sure if that helps answer your questions or not.